# Stack overflow when closing an application with opened form

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

When I create and show a form and close (terminate) the application when the form is still open, a stack overflow exception is thrown.

Showing the form:

```
private static void OpenSettings(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActionLog.Write("Opened Settings");
    form_Settings f_Settings = new form_Settings();
    f_Settings.Show();
}
```

Closing my Application by using the context menu callback:

```
private static void Quit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActionLog.Write("Exit");
    Settings.Serialize();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

the exception is thrown in the `GUI.form_Settings.Dispose` function. The function never exits and causes an infinite recursion.

If I don't have the window opened when I close my application, everything goes fine.

How is that?

// Edit:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Guess that's pretty standard, I couldn't find any other definitions. Also I want to mention that I'm using a custom framework (https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui), could this be a reason for this behavior?

Comment: If the exception is thrown in a `Dispose()` method, perhaps you should post that method? The code given is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: What happens if you add a call to f_settings.Close() after the call to Show()? Also, does this happen first time running OpenSettings?

Comment: Where is `Quit` called?

Comment: @TypeIA the function is pretty standard, at least I did not found anything special. I will edit the overriden dispose asap. Sorry.

Comment: @MikeCheel form is immediately turning black and no, it's even happening after opening the settings form some more times before closing/terminating the application.

Comment: Do you also have the stack trace from the debugger? It should reveal which function is caught in an infinite loop (probably one of the `components` referenced in your code)?

Comment: What's in `components`? Is it possible that it might either be the same object or might itself be trying to dispose this object?

Comment: The form is never disposed when you abort the program with Environment.Exit().  It could only be a finalizer that's causing this crash.  You probably have to look in that "custom framework" to get close to that.  Doing things in an abnormal way, like not cleanly shutting down, is a good way to trigger bugs in such code.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you have any suggestions for closing the application properly? I'm actually not using forms at all, only a settings window which is not opened all the time the app is running. It's mainly doing some tasks in the background and shows a notification. `ApplicationExit` closes all forms but not the application itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the custom framework ( https://github.com/viperneo/winforms-modernui ) is not working as intended. Everything works fine with the regular Windows Forms, no exception is thrown. But for some reason when using the framework, the exception is thrown if a form is not disposed before the application quits. Hopefully someone may read this when considering using this framework.

Thanks to Hans Passant for the hint regarding the custom framework!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are victim of a recursive call. Look at the stack trace when the exception is thrown and you will see which methods are called repeatedly. Probably one of the actions in `Quit` is triggering an event which calls `Quit` again.

See [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) on Wikipedia.

---

**UPDATE** (in response to your comment)

I would add a flag, telling whether the object was disposed.

```
private bool _disposed = false;

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed) {
        _disposed = true;

        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
            components = null; // Now they cannot be disposed again.
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

But try to understand why it is called recursively. There might be another bug hidden somewhere else.

Comment: Did that already but there was only this specific function over and over again. No other functions were logged, at least the stack trace window doesn't show me more entries.

Comment: Well this is exactly the function being called in a recursive way. By "this function" you probably mean `Quit`. How, where and when is `Quit` called?

Comment: No, the stack trace only contains plenty of entries of this line: `Test.exe!Test.form_Settings.Dispose(bool disposing) Line 21 C#`. Nothing else. Quit is a context menu callback (if the user clicks on the menu item). The context menu is attached to a `NotifyIcon` at the start of the application.

Comment: Thanks for your snippet but I won't use it since it seems quite dangerous to me. There must be reason why this function actually is recursive and I'm not feeling right about manipulating this since it could effect other modules. Oh and by the way, glad to see a german has answered to my question. :)